# How do I identify and extract events from a time-series dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a time series dataset that looks like this:
[The time-series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y88C2.png)

After I import the dataset into a pandas dataframe in Python, I would like to:

- Identify all of the increases above zero as individual events
- Calculate the area under the curve for each event
- Store the value of the area along with the start time and end time of the event

Any pointers on how I could approach this? I have a little experience with unsupervised learning. However, I'm having trouble even starting out with this because I'm not sure how to define conditions to identify an event.

Comment: Hi, this is a broad question and I'm guessing there are a lot of different ways to solve it. Can you edit your question to show what you've tried or considered so far?

Comment: Hi, I just edited it. I'm having trouble even starting out because I'm not sure how to define an event.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code with a toy dataset that uses pandas `shift` and comparison operators like `gt` (greater-than) and `ne` (not-equal) to identify the starts of peaks. I'm creating a new column in `df` that is `True` if the current row is the start of a new peak, otherwise `False`. I hope it's helpful to play around with this example, otherwise I'd suggest trying to find similar questions, maybe using key-words like "peak-finding".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create data like what you've shared
#this is random, but repeatable with the seed
#choose a random value between 0 and 3 and repeat it between 2 and 5 times
#then always go back to 0 for two timepoints
np.random.seed(1)
num_time = 100
values = []

while len(values) < num_time:
    value = np.random.random()*3
    repeat = np.random.randint(2,5)
    values.extend([value]*repeat+[0,0])
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time':range(num_time),
    'value':values[:num_time],
})



#add a new column with the 'peak group' of each value
#the shifting is to identify when the timeseries changes from less-than-threshold to more-than-threshold
threshold = 0.5 #could set this to zero if you'd like
passed_threshold = df['value'].gt(threshold)
df['peak_start'] = passed_threshold.ne(passed_threshold.shift(1)) & passed_threshold

#plotting to show the marked peak starts with orange dots
plt.plot(df.time, df.value)
plt.plot(df.loc[df.peak_start,'time'],df.loc[df.peak_start,'value'],'o')
```

[image]